# How can I get a curve of best fit using polyfit, when the x values are datetimes?

Tags: python, numpy, datetime, scipy, curve-fitting

An overview:
I have a Django site, where I graph data. I need to generate a polynomial curve of best fit, but the x values for the graphs are either dates or datetimes. I am using polyfit on a numpy array. When I try to convert the datetimes into integers or floats, using `datetime_object.timestamp()` I get really weird coefficient values and the graph does not match the data at all. Is there any way that I can use the polyfit method with datetimes (or dates) to get more normal coefficient values that fit the data better?

```py
milliseconds = []
for i in pricingDateTimes:
    dt_obj = datetime.strptime(i, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    milliseconds.append(dt_obj.timestamp() * 1000)  # I have also tried division by powers of 10 to get more reasonable coefficients
    x = array(milliseconds)
    y = array(pricingMetricData)
    quadratic = polyfit(x, y, 2)
```

So is there a way to get valid coefficients of data using polyfit and dates or datetimes as x values?
Is there another way that I could get the coefficients for the curve of best fit with datetimes or dates?

Thanks!

Comment: another note is that sometimes there is multiple days in between datetimes.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the time difference between each time entry and compute the cumulative sum.
And then use that as the x values.

```
>>> timeval
[datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 29, 18, 23, 25, 123830), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 29, 18, 23, 34, 123830), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 29, 18, 23, 40, 123830), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 29, 18, 23, 49, 123830), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 29, 18, 23, 53, 123830), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 29, 18, 23, 58, 123830), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 29, 18, 23, 58, 123830), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 29, 18, 24, 6, 123830), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 29, 18, 24, 11, 123830), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 29, 18, 24, 12, 123830), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 29, 18, 24, 21, 123830), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 29, 18, 24, 29, 123830), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 29, 18, 24, 29, 123830), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 29, 18, 24, 29, 123830), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 29, 18, 24, 38, 123830), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 29, 18, 24, 41, 123830), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 29, 18, 24, 41, 123830), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 29, 18, 24, 49, 123830), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 29, 18, 24, 58, 123830), datetime.datetime(2019, 11, 29, 18, 24, 59, 123830)]
>>> x = np.array([x.seconds for x in np.diff(np.array(timeval))]).cumsum()
>>> x
array([ 9, 15, 24, 28, 33, 33, 41, 46, 47, 56, 64, 64, 64, 73, 76, 76, 84,
       93, 94], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: What is timeval?

Comment: `millisecond` array in your case.

Comment: I named the array of `datetime` objects `timeval`

Answer (score 2):

There's an option to subtract the smallest timestamp so polyfit would work more stably:

```
# setup
times = ['2019-01-01 01:{:02d}:{:02d}'.format(mm,ss) for mm in range(24) for ss in range(0,60,10)]
l = len(times)

data = 3 * np.arange(l)**2 + 2 * np.arange(l) + 2.5 + np.random.rand(l)

# timestamps
timestamps = np.array([datetime.strptime(t,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S').timestamp()
                         for t in times])

# without this, the evaluation is really crazy
timestamps -= milliseconds.min()

quadratics = np.polyfit(timestamps, data, 2)
y_preds = quadratics[0] * milliseconds**2 + quadratics[1] * milliseconds + quadratics[2]

# data in blue
plt.plot(timestamps, data, linewidth=5)

# prediction in white
plt.plot(timestamps, y_preds, color='w')
```

Output:

[image]